# Method post not allowed

Tags: django

**Django 3.0.6.**

**pcask/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('image/', include(('image.urls', 'image'), namespace="image")),
]
```

**/pcask/image/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('bulk_upload/<int:pk>/', SeleniumBulkImageUpload.as_view(), name='bulk_upload'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class SeleniumBulkImageUpload(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = "image/selenium_bulk_upload.html"
    success_url = "/"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get("pk") # Breakpoint

        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files_dir = form.data['file_field']

        _upload_files(pk=pk, files_dir=files_dir)

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**image/selenium_bulk_upload.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'image:bulk_upload' 1 %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So far action path to first image is hardcoded. This is for debugging.
Anyway, action shouldn't be here at all.

**URLS**

Routing seems to be Ok.

In terminal:

```
>>> reverse("image:bulk_upload", kwargs={'pk':1})
'/image/bulk_upload/1/'
```

In template:

```
<form method="post" action="/image/bulk_upload/1/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="TUZ1eqgRDZmQsA49Lw0E7aY6obr6B6tjx2PTQtE9DxsaqVLOXt7S1u0UmvTd02DW">    <tr><th><label for="id_file_field">File field:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="file_field" maxlength="300" required id="id_file_field"></td></tr>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Problem**

Get request is routed to SeleniumBulkImageUpload. 
Necessary form shows in the browser.

Then I can see in the console of IDE:

```
[21/May/2020 18:12:42] "GET /image/bulk_upload/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9911
```

And I can stop at a breakpoint in get method of the parent class.

But for post method I get:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /image/bulk_upload/1/
Method Not Allowed: /image/bulk_upload/1/
```

And the interpreter doesn't stop at the breakpoint (shown in the code). And even if I remove my redefined post method completely, the problem doesn't disappear.

I tried to open ProcessFormView (a parent class) and put breakpoints there, then change the template:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'image:bulk_upload' 1 %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Result:

[image]

Well, it stopped. Then routing is ok.

**Request**:

```
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8000/image/bulk_upload/1/
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------286629394610736077032745264977
Content-Length: 409
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=Wb2wYtu6FM8z4dpvC9somiYXOkHV3qNxyAfXeDebSzG623FfTO6j8sqBRXRiM4DD; djdt=hide
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Thu, 21 May 2020 15:21:44 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: GET, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
```

Could you give me a piece of advice here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `super().post()` in your `post()` method; instead you could return a `HttpResponse` directly (or using `redirect()`).

Example, instead of the line:

```
return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

try something like this

```
return redirect(self.success_url)
```

or

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, this doesn't solve the problem. In the post method I put a breakpoint. The interpreter can't reach post method at all.